# ElasticSearch: Collapse if two fields are equal

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a job board where jobs are considered equal if both the company and the job title are the same. In this case, I would like to collapse and keep only one result.

For the moment, I am only able to collapse one field using the following code:

> "collapse": {"field": "meta._company_name.raw"}

I would like to do something like:

> "collapse": {"field": "meta._company_name.raw" AND "job_title.raw"}

Answer (score 0):

[collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html#second-level-of-collapsing) supports second level of collapsing

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "meta._company_name.raw",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "by_job",
      "collapse": { "field": "job_title.raw" },
      "size": 10
    }
  }
}
```